# Why is PHP's mail() sending me dozens of blank emails?

Tags: php, wordpress, email, wordpress-theming

I'm using PHP's `mail()` function within a WordPress theme to send form submissions to my email.

However, `mail()` has automatically sent me at least 20 blank emails,

within the last five minutes, without being submitted.

Could someone shed some light on what I've done to create this situation?

Here is the code from my (`functions.php` file)

```
function send_my_form(){

  $form = array();
  $form['fstname']  = $_POST['fstname'];
  $form['lstname']  = $_POST['lstname'];
  $form['email']    = $_POST['email'];
  $form['message']  = $_POST['message'];

  $send_to  = 'fakeemail@gmail.com';
  $subject  = 'You\'ve recieved an email from' . $form['fstname'] . $form['fstname'];
  $return   = "-f" . $send_to;

  $message  = "First Name: " . $form['fstname'] . "\r\n";
  $message .= "Last Name: " . $form['lstname'] . "\r\n";
  $message .= "Email: " . $form['email'] . "\r\n";
  $message .= "Message: " . $form['message'] . "\r\n";

  $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . '\r\n';
  $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . '\r\n';
  $headers .= 'From: ' . $send_to . '\r\n';
  $headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $form['email'] . '\r\n';
  $headers .= 'Return-Path: ' . $send_to . '\r\n';
  $headers .= '\r\nX-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

  mail($send_to, $subject, $message, $headers, $return);
}
add_action('wp_head', 'send_my_form');
```

Comment: perhaps you should run this through a condition that only sends if the fields are set. If I had to guess, I'd say it's just running on page load because you are using wp_head as the hook.

Comment: Thanks @KaiQing which hook would you recommend for a standard form?

Comment: Well, there's no reason NOT to use wp_head so long as you have the conditions set to only run this if the fields are set. Do you know what I mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I mean by running it in a conditional. Verify the fields are set before running the mail script.

```
function send_my_form(){
  if(isset($_POST['fstname']) && isset($_POST['lstname']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['message']))
  {
    $form = array();
    $form['fstname']  = $_POST['fstname'];
    $form['lstname']  = $_POST['lstname'];
    $form['email']    = $_POST['email'];
    $form['message']  = $_POST['message'];

    $send_to  = 'fakeemail@gmail.com';
    $subject  = 'You\'ve recieved an email from' . $form['fstname'] . $form['fstname'];
    $return   = "-f" . $send_to;

    $message  = "First Name: " . $form['fstname'] . "\r\n";
    $message .= "Last Name: " . $form['lstname'] . "\r\n";
    $message .= "Email: " . $form['email'] . "\r\n";
    $message .= "Message: " . $form['message'] . "\r\n";

    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . '\r\n';
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . '\r\n';
    $headers .= 'From: ' . $send_to . '\r\n';
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $form['email'] . '\r\n';
    $headers .= 'Return-Path: ' . $send_to . '\r\n';
    $headers .= '\r\nX-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($send_to, $subject, $message, $headers, $return);
  }
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean would something like `if(!isset($_POST['submit'])) { return; }` work as well?

Comment: It would but be careful with that. Submit is a very common name for a submit button. That would trigger if any form with submit is sent. The way it is in this example is pretty specific. You'd be pretty safe assuming this will only send for your form. Side note, contact form 7 is a very useful free plugin that handles all this for you. Have you looked into that?